# Jaspersoft studio json data adapter book or subreport document is Empty

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I am trying to do something really simple yet after searching for the past few days I could not find an answer, I need some help on this one.

**What I am trying to do:** 
I have multiple reports so A4 portrait some landscape, some with just static text some with tables, some with tables and variables and I want to put merge them together.

They work 100% individually.

Tried to make a master report with subreports did not work, tried the book approach did not work, I always get Document is empty, or if I try to manipulate the data query I get all kind of weird stuff.

Now I will try to make this example as simple as possible.

**JSON data: (New data Adapter)**

```
{
  "name": "Sample Name",
  "people":[
    {
      "who": "Person 1"
    },
    {
      "who": "Person 2"
    },
    {
      "who": "Person 3"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Book master report:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Empty_Book" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" sectionType="Part" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" uuid="d2716064-8ae4-40cf-a575-33afba400e3a">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter "/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks" value="true"/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <detail>
        <part uuid="69d6ca13-26f6-425f-bff9-395c5b9c183b">
            <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_CONNECTION">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["Blank_A4_2.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </p:subreportPart>
        </part>
        <part uuid="055c9f89-88b4-4270-b6ef-addb2eac3e56">
            <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                <subreportParameter name="REPORT_CONNECTION">
                    <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                </subreportParameter>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["Blank_A4_Landscape_1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </p:subreportPart>
        </part>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Blank_A4_2.jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="bd2bd70c-5a0d-4c3f-b81d-4d5d7731153d">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter "/>
    <queryString language="json">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="name"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="150" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="eef5f1dc-3d96-4008-8321-ef0be92d42d4"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="50" y="30" width="100" height="30" uuid="cbe6173f-5399-45ec-926b-ff6f48b4fb0c"/>
                <text><![CDATA[name]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**Blank_A4_Landscape_1.jrxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_Landscape_1" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="62f06d09-42b5-4471-baa5-5aed60cc5fc4">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter "/>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="eb54ec0d-0c60-44af-8476-e44f40560dee">
        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="New Data Adapter "/>
        <queryString language="json">
            <![CDATA[people]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="who" class="java.lang.String">
            <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="who"/>
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[who]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString language="JSON">
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.json.field.expression" value="name"/>
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="175">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="132" y="81" width="100" height="30" uuid="5cce1f44-2a8b-42ad-a03d-4c294f02d31c"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="140" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="110" y="45" width="200" height="40" uuid="75a06812-f9a0-4b0f-9a08-efec60d0b555"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Dataset1" uuid="acd62160-c07c-4c00-b6b4-9ef001d1585d">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("people")]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="200" uuid="253a610c-a780-4690-8cce-8a03597ef016">
                        <jr:detailCell height="30">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="200" height="30" uuid="910a7e24-c02b-4b21-8c9d-6a3dfda21794"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{who}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Tested all files before posting, individually they work, I have no params to send to the subreports, I tried looping over the array and still nothing I always get document is Empty no matter what I do.

Answer (score 2):

Passing the `REPORT_CONNECTION` to each subreport part has no effect. It's value will be non-null for JDBC connections only. So there's no reason to pass it.

You could have your setup running by tying each subreport to the Data Adapter file:

1. Export the Data Adapter to a file, say JSON_DA.xml, on the same level with your reports.
2. Add this property to each of the subreports:

   ```
   <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.data.adapter" value="JSON_DA.xml"/>
   ```

   (This could also be done by setting the Default Data Adapter in the Report Properties tab)
3. Recompile each subreport then preview the Master report again.

All this is necessary because JasperSoft Studio does not inject the Data Adapter into each subreport at runtime. It only injects it when each report is individually run(previewed) by automatically setting the `com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter` property.

Comment: The step of recompile is very important.